# Why jQuery it is not able to manage this JSON?

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I've a C# webservice that return this json:

```
{"data":"2"}
```

Yes it does. If I load the link from the browser I can see this output. The method is:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void IsFacebookPageLiked()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(new { data = "2" }));
}
```

I call it with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success: " + data);
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, text, error) {
        console.log("fail: " + error);
    }
});
```

but the result is always:

```
fail: (an empty string)
```

What's wrong with the code? And why it raise an exception?

Comment: What is the status code on the response? (See network tab).

Comment: The status is of course 200 OK

Comment: Maybe the content type is not technically supported on the server (aka the server is not setting the appropriate header). Remove that line and see if it works.

Comment: Just a side note: use `console.log("success: ", data);`

Comment: Tried. Also removing `dataType: "json"`. Nothing change.

Comment: @markzzz remove `contentType`

Comment: @m59: as I said, already tried.

Comment: @markzzz you said `dataType` :)

Comment: I mean: tried to remove it and "also" dataType.

Comment: Is this being tested on a real server or on localhost... or across domains? (wondering if this is a security issue)

Comment: Definitely a server issue if the response is blank. jQuery can't stop the browser from at least getting the requested document.

Comment: across domains. But I've put <webServices><protocols><add name="HttpGet"/> <add name="HttpPost"/> </protocols> </webServices>` inside the web.config

Comment: What does fiddler say is sent and returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not jQuerys fault. There must be server-side error. Otherwise jQuery wouldn't step into the `error` callback.

#### How can you be sure, it isn't a client-side fault

- Inspect your network traffic (using a traffic monitor, firebug or just a native developer tool of the browser). Maybe you can find a hint (e.g. in the status) of your response. Maybe your request isn't sent as expected.
- Check the response params of your callback function (text & error).

#### Possible solution

I would give this a try:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void IsFacebookPageLiked()
{
    SimpleMessage message = new SimpleMessage() {Message = "Hello World"};
    string json = JsonConvert.Serialize(message);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Comment: Fixed with `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing public void IsFacebookPageLiked() to
public static string IsFacebookPagedLiked() and then return the response.

Comment: It says "IsFacebookPageLiked Web Service method name is not valid"